# how to make elements tagged with the ng-disabled directive always disabled?

Tags: angularjs

I need to disable any element that has been marked with ng-disabled and have angular ignore the conditional logic in the html tag.

My goal is to mark a record as read only and stop any of the ng-disabled logic in the view.

Currently I have a directive that marks all controls as disabled but any control with ng-disabled will enable it's self based on it's assigned condition.

Comment: Explain your use case. This seems like a very non-Angular request. Maybe there is an Angular way to solve your problem.

Comment: When a user has readonly permission on a route,  I want to disable all the controls on the form ignoring what ng-disable was set to.

Comment: ng-disabled="fieldCondition || globalCondition"... there are no global ng-disabled, but you can to implement easily this component (something like global-disabled="myCondition")